# htaccess rewrite with Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want to rewrite a url like

> localhost/public/5/issue?readerVersion=2.0

to

> localhost/public/interface/getissuefile/projectID/5/readerVersion/2.0

I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^\/(.*)\/issue?readerVersion=(.*)$ \/interface\/getissuefile\/projectID/$1/readerVersion/$2 [R=301]
```

but this doesn't work. Zend throw me this Error:

> Invalid controller specified (5)

How can i fix that?

Comment: you should use routes instead of messing with the htaccess ,

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l is checking if the path is a symbolic link which you don't want, try removing it

Comment: ZF do this by default ... just don't change .htaccess file